# Testing prop drilling with Enzyme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I want to write an integration test to assert that a when a parent component drills certain values or properties to a child component, that component receives said values and renders them properly. Below I have two component examples and an example test. Of course, the test is not accurate, but I'm wondering how I can use enzyme to accomplish this? Thanks!

**sampleComponent.js:**

```
import React from 'react';

const SampleComponent = () => (
  <div test-attr="div">
    <SampleChildComponent title="Sample title" />
  </div>
);

export default SampleComponent;
```

**sampleChildComponent.js:**

```
import React from 'react';

const SampleChildComponent = ({ title }) => <h3 test-attr="h">{title}</h3>;

export default SampleChildComponent;
```

**sampleComponent.test.js:**

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import SampleComponent from './sampleComponent';
import SampleChildComponent from './sampleChildComponent';

test('renders component without errors', () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<SampleComponent />);
  const childWrapper = shallow(<SampleChildComponent />);
  expect(childWrapper.text()).toEqual('sample title');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

To render child components you should use `mount` instead of `shallow`:

```
import { mount } from 'enzyme'
import React from 'react'
import SampleChildComponent from './sampleChildComponent'
import SampleComponent from './sampleComponent'

test('renders component without errors', () => {
  const wrapper = mount(<SampleComponent />)
  expect(wrapper.find(SampleChildComponent).text()).toEqual('sample title')
})
```

Comment: Thanks. i know how to test if a component properly renders with props. What I want to test is that, if a parent component renders, that a subsequent child component renders the props it receives from that parent component.